# How to implement test-flight crash reporting in swift

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, testflight

I am developing an app in swift. I integrated test-flight SDK for remote logging. Now I want to use other test-flgiht SDK provided features. One of them is crash reporting. In the test-flight provided sample code c functions are there. How can I implement those c calls
The sample code test-flight provided

```
  /*
   My Apps Custom uncaught exception catcher, we do special stuff here, and TestFlight takes care of the rest
  */
  void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a exception");
    // Save application data on crash
  }
  /*
   My Apps Custom signal catcher, we do special stuff here, and TestFlight takes care of the rest
  */
  void SignalHandler(int sig) {
    NSLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a signal");
    // Save application data on crash
  }

  -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // installs HandleExceptions as the Uncaught Exception Handler
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
    // create the signal action structure 
    struct sigaction newSignalAction;
    // initialize the signal action structure
    memset(&newSignalAction, 0, sizeof(newSignalAction));
    // set SignalHandler as the handler in the signal action structure
    newSignalAction.sa_handler = &SignalHandler;
    // set SignalHandler as the handlers for SIGABRT, SIGILL and SIGBUS
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGILL, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &newSignalAction, NULL);
    // Call takeOff after install your own unhandled exception and signal handlers
    [TestFlight takeOff:@"Insert your Application Token here"];
    // continue with your application initialization
  }
```

Link for the above code:http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829558-how-do-i-implement-crash-reporting-

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking for something similar too :P

Comment: i think you can implement this one in a separate objective c file and use it in swift file. @CamiloAguilar

Comment: I actually did that but forgot to post what I did here. For the record, I wrote to testflight because I was just getting the count of crashs but no the info. They were having issues. Haven't check back.